# Find and remove div with id in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a multiple div inside the main div. my question is how can i find and remove those div with the a certain data id?

```
     <div id="tray1"> 
           <div id="oz" class="crtbody"></div>
           <div id="it" class="crtbody"></div>
     </div>
```

i try this code but nothing happen:

```
var getId="oz";
$("#tray1").find(".crtbody [data-id='" + getId + "']").remove();
```

thank

Comment: `$("#oz").remove();` ?

Comment: You are trying to remove a div which has attr data-id equal to getId

Comment: You are using the term `data id` (which assumes `data-id="oz"` etc), but are actually using plain old id's. Can you provide a bit more detail on the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var getId="oz";
$("#tray1").find("#" + getId).remove();
```

You don't need to use `data-id` attribute as you are using `id` in your HTML markup.
Also, if your markup is correct, you should only have one unique `id` in your DOM and therefore you could do:

```
$("#oz").remove();   // or $('#' + getId).remove();
```

Comment: Why use find? It's slower than $("#id"), with the 2nd one jQuery uses the native ID selector, which is the fastest way

Comment: @FezVrasta I don't know how his HTML markup is and therefore he might be using duplicate IDs through the DOM, just in case :) I already explained it in my answer.

Comment: if he uses duplicate IDs the markup is invalid and he should fix the duplicate IDs, not use a solution to workaround the error.

Comment: @FezVrasta well, I also provided the answer in case his markup is correct. If he knows how to read he will get the idea :)

Comment: what if i put data-id instead of id, how can i code data-id as selector?   $(".crtbody [data-id='" + getId + "']") is this incorrect?

Comment: @user2731440 you are using `id` in your HTML markup right now. Why do you want to use `data-id`?

Comment: In case you want to use `data-id`, you would need to delete the whitespace you had: `$("#tray1").find(".crtbody[data-id='" + getId + "']").remove();` but it will be slower and has no sense if the `id` is unique in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

use [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), since id will be unique in a document there is no need to use any search context

```
$("#" + getId).remove();
```